# maintaining selection in UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Can i maintain the selected state of UISegmentViewControl segments??
i.e can keep a segment appear selected even if the user selects another segment??
I dont seem to find anything that does this anywhere!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible out of the box. (See [How can I enable multiple segments of a UISegmentedControl to be selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029570/how-can-i-enable-multiple-segments-of-a-uisegmentedcontrol-to-be-selected).)

You could try something like [this code](http://mac-objective-c.blogspot.com/2010/01/uisegmentedcontrol-subclass-that.html) to provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way arround this.I placed dark colored image behind each segment and set their hidden property to true.Then i decresed the alpha value of the uisegmented control.Then in the code when a segment is clicked i turn the visibility on or off accordingly,so multiple  segments appear selected

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be using a category:

```
#import <UIKit/UISegmentedControl.h>
@interface UISegmentedControl (MultiSelect) 
@end
```

Doing this, you have in principle access to private member variables of   UISegmentedControl    . In particular, you have access to the array holding the button segments, which you can manipulate according to your needs by overriding     setSelectedSegmentIndex:selectedSegmentIndex:    .However, for various reasons, the attributes declared as private still shouldn't be accessed directly, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429226/accessing-private-variable-in-category-results-in-linker-error). As also suggested there, you can rather abuse KVC. So the implementation could look as follows:

```
@implementation UISegmentedControl (MultiSelect)
- (void)setSelectedSegmentIndex:(NSInteger)selectedSegmentIndex {
    NSMutableArray *pArraySegments = [self valueForKey:@"segments"]; 
    if ((pArraySegments) && (selectedSegmentIndex >= 0) && (selectedSegmentIndex < [pArraySegments count])) {
        UIButton *pSegment = (UIButton*)[pArraySegments objectAtIndex:selectedSegmentIndex];
        pSegment.selected ? (pSegment.selected = NO) : (pSegment.selected = YES);
    }
}
@end
```

This works for me. However, since I now read [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633924/uisegmentedcontrol-behaviour), I'm not quite sure if this is really a valid approach.