# Can subclass override non-public methods

Tags: objective-c, oop

I have two classes: `BatchDownloader`, `SpeechDownlader`

`BatchDownloader` is the base class, and `SpeechDownloader` inherited it.

In `BatchDownloader`, whenever one file was downloaded, `-(void)downloadComplete:task` will be called.

But in `SpeechDownloader`, I also want to post a notification in `downloadComplete:task`.

Can I just write the method with the same name in `SpeechDownloader`'s implementation ? or there is a better way ?

Thanks.

p.s. I don't want to make `-(void)downloadComplete:task` public, because it should only be called by itself.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by posting a notification from speechdownloader. What are you trying to do? That may tell us more information about your problem.

Comment: I found this to be the best answer. Easy, simple and safe:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678463/accessing-a-method-in-a-super-class-when-its-not-exposed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you implement a method in a subclass that has the same name as a private method in a superclass, your subclass method *will* be called on instances of your subclass.

i.e., if you implement a method in your superclass like this, without declaring it anywhere:

```
@implementation classA

- (void)doSomething {
    NSLog("a");
}
```

Then, in your subclass implementation, implement a method with the same name:

```
@implementation subclassOfA

- (void)doSomething {
    NSLog("b");
}
```

When you call `doSomething` on an instance of your subclass, the subclass implementation **will** be called instead of the superclass implementation, so the code in this example will result in "b" being printed to the console.

However, if you also want to access the superclass implementation of the method, you can use:

```
- (void)doSomething {
    [super doSomething];
    NSLog("b");
}
```

This will also call the superclass implementation. If you get a compile error (due to the method being private and `super` not appearing to implement it), you can use `[super performSelector:@selector(doSomething)]` instead to do exactly the same thing.

This happens because of the way the Objective-C runtime looks up method calls. Since these methods have exactly the same method signature (same name, return type and arguments [none]), they are considered equal, and the runtime always checks the class of the object before looking in superclasses, so it will find the subclass method implementation first.

Also, this means you can do this:

```
classA *test = [subclassOfA new];
[test doSomething];
```

And, surprise surprise, the console will print "**b**" (Or "**a b**" if you called the `super` implementation too).

Comment: Thanks for your great illustration, problem solved. It seems typo will sometimes be an issue, right?

Comment: Obviously, since that means the method name is different, and the method signatures are therefore different as far as the runtime is concerned, because it doesn't have a spellchecker.

Answer (score 1):

If you implement the method with the same method signature it will be called faith your implementation, public or not.