# UIControlEventValueChanged not working when i tapped an already selected segment section

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, ipad-2, uicontrolevents

My aim is to trigger  **UIControlEventValueChanged** delegate again when i tapped an already selected segment .

So i have referred the below links

[uisegmentedcontrol-register-taps-on-selected-segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620972/uisegmentedcontrol-register-taps-on-selected-segment)

[maintaining-selection-in-uisegmentedcontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468012/maintaining-selection-in-uisegmentedcontrol)

As per the links i have created a uisegmentedcontrol subclass , implemented the `- (void) setSelectedSegmentIndex:(NSInteger)toValue {` method and wrote the codes (from the above links).

Its worked fine with Ipad1. However the **setSelectedSegmentIndex** in the inherited/sub class is not triggering in Ipad2 when tapped an already selected segment!!!! however it is working fine when i tapped an unselected segment index.

The code i done is below

**Main Class**

```
ReselectableSegmentControl *firstNextSegmentedControl = [[ReselectableSegmentControl alloc] init];
firstNextSegmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(xCordinate, 255, 188, 50);
firstNextSegmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
firstNextSegmentedControl.tag = index + 1;      
[firstNextSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(firstNextThenSegmentedControlValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[firstNextSegmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NoTimerCounter.png"] atIndex:0 animated:YES];
[firstNextSegmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Timer.png"] atIndex:1 animated:YES];
[firstNextSegmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Counter.png"] atIndex:2 animated:YES];              
firstNextSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

[self.view addSubview:firstNextSegmentedControl];
[firstNextSegmentedControl release];
firstNextSegmentedControl = nil;
```

**UISegmentSubClass .h file**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ReselectableSegmentControl : UISegmentedControl {    

}

@end
```

**UISegmentSubClass .m file**

```
-(void)setSelectedSegmentIndex:(NSInteger )selectedValue{

    if (selectedValue==self.selectedSegmentIndex) {

           [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
       [super setSelectedSegmentIndex:selectedValue];  
}
```

or

```
-(void)setSelectedSegmentIndex:(NSInteger )selectedValue{


    if (self.selectedSegmentIndex == selectedValue) {           

              //doing my operation if tapped again the selected value.

    else {

        super.selectedSegmentIndex = selectedValue;
    }
}
```

or

```
- (void) setSelectedSegmentIndex:(NSInteger)toValue {

      if (self.selectedSegmentIndex == toValue) {

          [super setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment];

    } else {

       [super setSelectedSegmentIndex:toValue];        
   }
```

}

The all above methods are not working with Ipad2.

Any help on this issue is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to trigger a value changed method without changing the value. Just create a new method that happens at the event you want and use that instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Phew... finally i got the solution..

I have used **UITapGestureRecognizer** instead of using `addTarget:self action:@selector()`

Now my code is looking like,

```
UISegmentedControl *firstNextSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] init];
firstNextSegmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(xCordinate, 255, 188, 50);
firstNextSegmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
firstNextSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0; 

[firstNextSegmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NoTimerCounter.png"] atIndex:0 animated:YES];
[firstNextSegmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Timer.png"] atIndex:1 animated:YES];
[firstNextSegmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Counter.png"] atIndex:2 animated:YES];          

               //Added UITapGestureRecognizer instead of using addTarget: method        
                UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];         
                tapGesture addTarget:self action:@selector(firstNextThenSegmentedControlValueChanged:) ];
                [firstNextSegmentedControl addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
                [tapGesture release];
                tapGesture = nil;

[self.view addSubview:firstNextSegmentedControl];
[firstNextSegmentedControl release];
firstNextSegmentedControl = nil;



-(void)firstNextThenSegmentedControlValueChanged:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture{  

   UISegmentedControl *segmentControl = (UISegmentedControl *)tapGesture.view;      

   switch (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {

    case 0:
     [self doIt:segmentControl];                
    break;  

    default:    
    break;

    }
}
```