# What is the color or tint of the bar style UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to make a button that has the same appearance as one of the segments of a bar style segment like this color:

[image]

But I dont know how to acheive the same gradient as it. My goal is to make a segment control with buttons that looks the same but you can select multiple "segments"

Comment: Why not take the image you've uploaded here, crop a section of the gradient, and use that as a resizable image?

Answer (score 2):

**1. For enabling multiple selection**,configure the **Selection** attribute of the segmented control as **Multiple** or do a search  for custom multiple selection segments.

**Selection**.

Specifies the tracking mode of the segmented control. The possible options are:

**Multiple**: This corresponds to the constant NSSegmentSwitchTrackingSelectAny and specifies that any segment can be selected.

**2.For the appearance**,use the background gradient image

```
[mySegmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient.png"] atIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

For more,please refer my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297745/uicontroleventvaluechanged-not-working-when-i-tapped-an-already-selected-segment/11308903#11308903)

Comment: I dont see where I can set the control to multiple?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this piece of code if you have images for selected and normal state images in gradient.

```
UIImage *segmentNormal = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segmentNormal.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

UIImage *segmentSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segmentSelected.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

All you want is here [link](https://github.com/yonat/MultiSelectSegmentedControl)

and for segments appearance you can set `[UISegmentedControl appearance]` property.

Comment: I have tried this subclass but it does not work correctly with storyboards

Comment: @BluGeni:you are right , you can try this with programmatically in storyboard